# Container Managed Transactions and Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, ejb-3.0, message-driven-bean

In [the The Java EE 6 Tutorial, 
Chapter 17 A Message-Driven Bean Example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbpk/index.html) ,
I came across this:

```
 @MessageDriven(mappedName="jms/Queue", activationConfig =  {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                              propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                              propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class SimpleMessageBean implements MessageListener {
    @Resource
    private MessageDrivenContext mdc;
...
```

Since the MDB is transacted - (default value for transaction attributes points to `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED` and `TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)`)

how makes `@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")` any sence?

In [Controlling Message Acknowledgment](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfw/index.html) I read

> In transacted sessions (see Using JMS API Local Transactions), acknowledgment happens automatically when a transaction is committed. If a transaction is rolled back, all consumed messages are redelivered.

This got me confused; I would expect **not to declare acknowledgeMode** here (since we are in a transacted session)

Answer (score 1):

In short: this property won't affect message acknowledgment for MDB using CONTAINER transaction.

For answer you can look [EJB 3.2 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html)

> JMS message-driven beans should not attempt to  use the JMS API for
>   message acknowledgment. Mes
>   - sage acknowledgment is automatically handled by the  container. If the message-driven bean uses con
>   - tainer-managed transaction demarcation, message acknowledgment is handl ed automatically as a part of  the transaction commit. If
>   bean-man aged transaction demarcation is us ed, the message receipt
>   cannot be  part of the bean-managed transaction,  and, in this case,
>   the receipt is acknowledged  by the container. If  bean-managed
>   transaction   demarcation   is   used,   the   Bean   Provider   can
>   indicate   whether   JMS    AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE  semantics or 
>   DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE  semantics should apply by using the 
>   activationConfig   element  of  the   MessageDriven   annotation  or 
>   by  using  the   activation-config-property   deployment  descriptor  element.  The   property  name  used  to  specify  the   acknowledgment mode is 
>   acknowledgeMode . If the  acknowledgeMode  property is not specified, 
>   JMS  AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE  semantics are assumed. The value of the 
>   acknowledgeMode  property  must be either  Auto-acknowledge  or 
>   Dups-ok-acknowledge  for a JMS message-driven bean.

So in your case this property will be affected only if you switch your bean to BMT by adding
`@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` annotation.

Also I recommend you to read [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074123/java-web-development/transaction-and-redelivery-in-jms.html) about Transaction and redelivery in JMS

Comment: thanks! if you agree that my question is useful you could reward it by upvoting it.